# What is the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

A random sample of size $7$ is drawn from a distribution with p.d.f $$f_{\theta}(x)=\frac{1+x^2}{3\theta(1+\theta^2)}, -2\theta \le x \le \theta,\;x>0 \;\text{and otherwise zero}$$ 
and the observations are $12,-54,26,-2,24,17,-39$. What is the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$?

> My Attempt:

Fix $x_1=12,x_2=-54,x_3=26,\cdots,x_7=-39$.

$L(\theta,x)=\prod_{i=1}^{7}\left(\frac{1+x_{i}^2}{3\theta(1+\theta^2)}\right)$. So, $$l(\theta,x)=\sum_{i=1}^{7}\log\left(\frac{1+x_{i}^2}{3\theta(1+\theta^2)}\right)$$
Now, $$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta}=\sum_{i=7}^{7}\left(\frac{3\theta(1+\theta^2)}{1+x_{i}^2}\right)\cdot \frac{-(3\theta(1+\theta^2)(1+x_{i}^2))}{(3\theta(1+\theta^2))^2}$$
Now, we just need to equate $\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta}=0$ and find answer in terms of $x_i$

But after this, I am unable to find the MLE $\hat{\theta}$.

Please help me to solve this question. Thanks.

Comment: No differentiation required. MLE is the smallest possible value of $\theta$ since the likelihood is decreasing in $\theta$. So what is the smallest possible value of $\theta$ when $-2\theta<x_i<\theta$ ?

Comment: So, we just need to see $L(\theta,x)$? and that value would be $27$ since $x_i=-54$ is present.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Is that all that we have to do?

Comment: $$\text{“Now, we just need to equate }\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta}=0 \text{ and find answer in terms of }x_i\text{"} $$ That is a rash statement. In cases where the boundaries of the support of the distribution depend on $\theta,$ you can have an endpoint maximum, at which the derivative is not $0.$ And more generally, reposing ones faith in algorithms without understanding is hazardous, to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$f_\theta(x)=\frac{ 1+x^2}{3\theta(1+\theta^{2})}
1_{\{-2\theta \leq x\leq \theta\}}$$

$$f_\theta(x_1,\cdots,x_7)=\frac{\prod( 1+x_i^2)}{3^7\theta^7(1+\theta^{2})^{7}}
\prod_{i=1}^{7} 1_{\{-2\theta \leq x_i \leq \theta\}}$$

The term $\prod_{i=1}^7 1_{\{-2\theta \leq x_i \leq \theta\}}$ is zero except if $\{-2\theta \leq \min (x_i)\leq \max (x_i)  \leq \theta\}$. Define $M=\max (x_i)$
and $m=\min (x_i)$ so

$$f_\theta(x_1,\cdots,x_7)=\frac{\prod( 1+x_i^2)}{3^7\theta^7(1+\theta^{2})^{7}}
 1_{\{M\leq \theta \}} 1_{\{-m/2 \leq \theta \}}
==\frac{\prod( 1+x_i^2)}{3^7\theta^7(1+\theta^{2})^{7}}
 1_{\{\max(M,-m/2)\leq \theta \}}
=
\frac{\prod( 1+x_i^2)}{3^7\theta^7(1+\theta^{2})^{7}}
 1_{\{27\leq \theta \}}.$$

Now maximize 
$$\frac{1}{3^7\theta^7(1+\theta^2)^7}$$ with condition

$$27\leq \theta$$

Comment: It seems OK to me.

Comment: at $\theta=26$ it attains max, then is that the answer?

Comment: Yes.I think $\theta =26$ maximize it.

Comment: But the answer for the given question is $\theta=27$.

Comment: I did not see any issue in the solution. (except forget define$m=\min(x_i)$). So I think the answer is 26.

Comment: $\theta>-\min x_i/2$ and $\theta>\max x_i$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thank you. (Some times It happen!!!)

Comment: Now I think the answer is 27!!!!!

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help

Comment: You are welcome.